# Multiply/add/divide/subtract values in a class

Tags: java, math

I have this very simple class that looks like this:

```
public class Vector2{

    public final double x;
    public final double y;

    public Vector2(final double x, final double y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Is it possible for me to do something like this in Java?

```
Vector2 amount = new Vector2(10, 40) * 2;

System.out.println(amount.x);  // Prints 20
System.out.println(amount.y);  // Prints 80
```

Comment: No its not possible in Java.

Comment: No, Java doesn't have user-definable overloaded operators.

Comment: _No_ but you can add method multiply() something like `new Vector2(10,40).multiply(2)`

Comment: Nope. You'll have to make a `multiply(int n)` method.  You can't use `*` like that.